# React: dynamic GET URL in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update the state 'allMovieList' to render a list of movies.

The idea was to set a dynamic URL in my GET request, by updating the 'page' state when clicking on the button. Unfortunately this doesn't trigger a re-rendering since the request is made only one time in componentDidMount() method.

```
state = {
    allMovieList: [],
    page: 1
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.changePage();
}

async changePage() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/4/discover/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&page=${this.state.page}`);
        const movieList = response.data.results.slice(0, 10);
        const movies = movieList.map(movie => movie);
        const totalPages = response.data.total_pages;
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            allMovieList: movies,

        })
    } catch (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}

onNextPage = () => {
    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
        return { page: previousState.page + 1 };
    });
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className='MovieList'>
            ...
            <button onClick={this.onNextPage}></button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

To solve this, I tried to call the changePage() function inside my onNextPage() function.

```
onNextPage = () => {
    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
        return { page: previousState.page + 1 };
    });
    this.changePage();
}
```

This partially solved this issue but for some reason the next page is actually only rendered on second click! I also noticed my component is being re-rendered twice on every click.

I also tried to call the changePage() function inside componentDidUpdate(), this solved the issue but now my app is constantly re-rendering which causes huge performance issues.

Can anyone help me with this? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1) Use `setState`'s callback function:

```
this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
    return { page: previousState.page + 1 };
}, this.changePage); // state will be updated when this gets called
```

Option 2) Use function arguments:

```
async changePage(page) {
  try {
    const response = await 
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/4/discover/movie?page=${page}`);
      ...
  }
}

...
onNextPage = () => {
  this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
    const page = previousState.page + 1
    this.changePage(page);
    return { page };
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this worked like a charm! I used the first option which I find very elegant.